# JSF Strategies For Long Lists in SelectOneMenu e.g. TimeZones

Tags: jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am implementing a way for a user to specify their timezone. Nothing new there. I want to hear what people say is a good strategy for handling cases when users need to select from a list of a couple hundred choices, but might not know the correct value for it in the list right away. I know I can use something like autocomplete, but that only works if people know what they are looking for. Sure countries should be obvious but... lowest common denominator (some people are dumb... like me ;).

There are something over 400 distinct iso timezones (not including things like EST, PST, etc. which I am not including). That is a long list. It can be conveniently divided if we let the user chose the country they are in first in say, another selectonemenu. But there are more than 200 countries. So how to present 200 countries that is easy and efficient to work with?

I have already created and packaged in a jar a number of classes to read from the Olson timezone files (iso3166.tab and zone.tab) and provide arraylists of timezone and and timezonecountries, including prioritizing specified countries to the top of the list. But now I would like to maybe learn a better way to present the countries and the timezones. I did this myself since I found it an easier and cleaner way to extract and correlate country codes and timezone codes.

Comment: i guess, as a user i'll prefer alphabatically ordered timezones n countries, rather than some other prioritization scheme

Comment: That's a given for sure. :) But I know that if you are primarily expecting users from say, North America, you might put Canada and America at the top of the list and then list the rest alphabetically. But it is still a long list.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular requirement, I can think of using a world map like you see in a Linux distro like Ubuntu centered at Greenwich. Then placing markers for the data that you have and letting the user select the nearest marker.

See Timezone selection for [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime)

For this you can make use the Primefaces [GMAP](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapMarkerSelect.jsf) component and add an overlay like this:

```
 LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323); 
 PlaceResult placeResultObj1 = new  new PlaceResult("660")

 //Basic marker  
 simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti", placeResultObj1));
```

PlaceResult.java

```
public class PlaceResult {
    private String utc_offset;

    public PlaceResult(String utc_offset){
        this.utc_offset = utc_offset;
    }

    public String getUtc_offset() {
        return utc_offset;
    }

    public void setUtc_offset(String utc_offset) {
        this.utc_offset = utc_offset;
    }

}
```

Another approach is to use the Places library from Google maps. Using that you can get the `google.maps.places.PlaceResult` object by various methods, I like the autocomplete feature where you can choose the city. After a city is selected you can show the utc_offset in the infowindow.

You can take a look at this [demo](http://jsbin.com/oyoluy/2)

Currently, it seems that most of the cities don't have utc_offset already set. One of the address I found that had utc_offset was

Newy Airport Transport Shuttle in Australia. Then you can pass the off_set as a input hidden parameter to submit the value to the server.

See also:

- [Google Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests)

Comment: Unfortunately that is too heavy weight a solution. I am more interested in what people do with selectonemenus. I could see this solution if I were building an installation wizard, but I think too much for general use.  I might try it as an exercise later but not at the moment. Thanks for the suggestion though.